# Detect Vehicle ( Bus, Car, Motorcycle, Bicycle,Train, Plane)

Tags: android, xamarin

How can i implement Detecting between bus, car , motorcycle, bicycle, train, plane based on xamarin and based on speed and distance user has travelled between two points

I have found activity recognition api on xamarin

but how can i make it detect between different vehicles?

Thanks

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/google-services/Location/ActivityRecognition/

Comment: It's impossible to detect such thing. However plane is easiest to detect, your phone is in airplane mode. :)

Comment: first think of how you would detect it in real life, and then convert that conditions to c#

Comment: I am not sure if this can fulfill all your need but you should give it a try. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/       Try adding different image urls to check if it can work for you. It detects whats inside the pic.